# Applying a function for all pairwise rows in two matrices under Numpy

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, matrix

I have two matrices:

```
import numpy as np

def create(n):
    M = array([[ 0.33840224,  0.25420152,  0.40739624],
               [ 0.35087337,  0.40939274,  0.23973389],
               [ 0.40168642,  0.29848413,  0.29982946],
               [ 0.17442095,  0.50982272,  0.31575633]])
    return np.concatenate([M] * n)

A = create(1)
nof_type = A.shape[1]       
I = np.eye(nof_type)
```

Matrix `A` dimension is `4 x 3` and I is `3 x 3`.
What I want to do is to

1. calculate a distance score for every row in `A` against every row in `I`.
2. for every row in `A` report the row id of `I` and the maximum score

So at the end of the day we have 4 x 2 matrix.
How an I achieve that?

This is the function that compute distance score between two numpy array.

```
def jsd(x,y): #Jensen-shannon divergence
    import warnings
    warnings.filterwarnings("ignore", category = RuntimeWarning)
    x = np.array(x)
    y = np.array(y)
    d1 = x*np.log2(2*x/(x+y))
    d2 = y*np.log2(2*y/(x+y))
    d1[np.isnan(d1)] = 0
    d2[np.isnan(d2)] = 0
    d = 0.5*np.sum(d1+d2)    
    return d
```

And in actual case `A` has number of rows with around 40K. So we really like it to be fast.

Using loopy way:

```
def scoreit (A, I):
    aoa = []
    for i, x in enumerate(A):
        maxscore = -10000
        id = -1

        for j, y in enumerate(I):
            distance = jsd(x, y) 
            #print "\t", i, j, distance
            if dist > maxscore:
                maxscore = distance
                id = j
        #print "MAX", maxscore, id
        aoa.append([maxscore,id])
    return aoa
```

It prints this result:

```
In [56]: scoreit(A,I)
Out[56]:
[[0.54393736529629078, 1],
 [0.56083720679952753, 2],
 [0.49502813447483673, 1],
 [0.64408263453965031, 0]]
```

Current timing:

```
In [57]: %timeit scoreit(create(1000),I)
1 loops, best of 3: 3.31 s per loop
```

Comment: So, `I` is always an identity array?

Comment: @Divakar: That is right!

Comment: Could you add any loopy code if you have tried and/or the expected output for the given sample? I am just not sure how the output can be of shape `(4,2)`.

Comment: Also, could you list the shapes of `A` and `I` for your actual case?

Comment: @Divakar: I updated with loopy way.

Comment: So, A would be `40000 x 3` and I `3x3` for the actual case?

Comment: @Divakar: Yes, `bigA = np.concatenate([A] * 40000)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can extend `I`'s dimensions to a `3D` array version at various places to bring in [`powerful broadcasting`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/user/basics.broadcasting.html) into play. We keep `A` as it is, because it's a huge array and we don't want to incur performance loss moving its elements around. Also, you can avoid that costly affair of checking for `NaNs` and summing with a single operation of [`np.nansum`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.nansum.html) that does summing over `non-NaNs`. Thus, the vectorized solution would look something like this -

```
def jsd_vectorized(A,I):

    # Perform "(x+y)" in a vectorized manner
    AI = A+I[:,None]

    # Calculate d1 and d2 using AI again in vectorized manner
    d1 = A*np.log2(2*A/AI)
    d2 = I[:,None,:]*np.log2((2*I[:,None,:])/AI)

    # Use np.nansum to ignore NaNs & sum along rows to get all distances
    dists = np.nansum(d1,2) + np.nansum(d2,2)

    # Pack the argmax IDs and the corresponding scores as final output   
    ID = dists.argmax(0)
    return np.vstack((0.5*dists[ID,np.arange(dists.shape[1])],ID)).T
```

---

**Sample run**

Loopy function to run original function code -

```
def jsd_loopy(A,I):
    dists = np.empty((A.shape[0],I.shape[0]))
    for i, x in enumerate(A):   
        for j, y in enumerate(I):
            dists[i,j] = jsd(x, y)
    ID = dists.argmax(1)
    return np.vstack((dists[np.arange(dists.shape[0]),ID],ID)).T
```

Run and verify -

```
In [511]: A = np.array([[ 0.33840224,  0.25420152,  0.40739624],
     ...:        [ 0.35087337,  0.40939274,  0.23973389],
     ...:        [ 0.40168642,  0.29848413,  0.29982946],
     ...:        [ 0.17442095,  0.50982272,  0.31575633]])
     ...: nof_type = A.shape[1]       
     ...: I = np.eye(nof_type)
     ...: 

In [512]: jsd_loopy(A,I)
Out[512]: 
array([[ 0.54393737,  1.        ],
       [ 0.56083721,  2.        ],
       [ 0.49502813,  1.        ],
       [ 0.64408263,  0.        ]])

In [513]: jsd_vectorized(A,I)
Out[513]: 
array([[ 0.54393737,  1.        ],
       [ 0.56083721,  2.        ],
       [ 0.49502813,  1.        ],
       [ 0.64408263,  0.        ]])
```

**Runtime tests**

```
In [514]: A = np.random.rand(1000,3)

In [515]: nof_type = A.shape[1]       
     ...: I = np.eye(nof_type)
     ...: 

In [516]: %timeit jsd_loopy(A,I)
1 loops, best of 3: 782 ms per loop

In [517]: %timeit jsd_vectorized(A,I)
1000 loops, best of 3: 1.17 ms per loop

In [518]: np.allclose(jsd_loopy(A,I),jsd_vectorized(A,I))
Out[518]: True
```

Comment: Thanks. With `out = jsd_vectorized(A,I)` Is there a way to make the index `ids =out[:,1:]` as integer? I'd like to use it to mask a list say `foo = ["a","b","c"]`

Comment: @neversaint Do something like `out[:,2].astype(int)`, where `out = jsd_vectorized(A,I)`?

Comment: BTW, why doing this `jsdout  = jsd_vectorized(A,I)` give me this warning `//anaconda/bin/ipython:4: RuntimeWarning: divide by zero encountered in log2
  from IPython import start_ipython
//anaconda/bin/ipython:4: RuntimeWarning: invalid value encountered in multiply
  from IPython import start_python`

Comment: @neversaint You can bring the ignore warnings code that you have in the question to this posted approach here as well, right? The output won't change, so you can basically ignore the warnings.